# Serializing tree structure in .NET in XML to a file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, tree

I have no problems with serialization of complete tree structure to a file in XML. However, I spend much time on the problem: how to serialize nodes of tree one-by-one in XML to file, because my tree is constantly building and I want to add new nodes to a file in parallel. What's the best way to do it?